# bash: For each line in a txt file match a regex and save it to a variable array

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, scripting

I am trying to read each line of the text file and extract the name before the .tst and store each match into a variable array. here is an example of the txt file:

```
    someTest.tst (/blah/blah/blah),
    someOtherfile.tst (/some/other/blah),
    hello.tst (/not/the/same/blah),
    hi.tst (/is/this/blah),
```

There is a bunch of whitespace on each line before the characters.

I would like to extract the following values and store them in a variable array:

```
someTest
someOtherfile
hello
hi
```

I have tried using sed and awk but my knowledge with either is not expert level status and thus I am having trouble achieving what I want. Any insight?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a regex for this at all.

```
arr=( )
while read -r name _; do
  [[ $name = *.tst ]] || continue # skip lines not containing .tst
  arr+=( "${name%.tst}" )
done <input.txt

declare -p arr # print array contents
```

- `read` accepts a list of destinations; fields (as determined by splitting input on the characters in `IFS`) are populated into variables as they're read, and the last destination receives all remaining content on a line (including whitespace). Thus, `read -r name _` puts the first field into `name`, and all remaining contents on the input line into a variable named `_`.
- `[[ $name = *.tst ]] || continue` skips all lines where the first field doesn't end in `.tst`.
- `"${name%.tst}"` expands to the contents of `"$name"`, with the suffix `.tst` removed if present.
- The `while read; do ...; done <inputfile` pattern is described in more detail in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

---

However, if you **wanted** to use a regex, that might look like this:

```
re='^[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+)[.]tst[[:space:]]'

arr=( )
while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ $line =~ $re ]] && arr+=( "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" )
done <input.txt

declare -p arr # print array contents
```

Using `[[ $string =~ $regex ]]` evaluates `$regex` as an ERE and, if it matches, puts the entirety of the matched content into `BASH_REMATCH[0]`, and any match groups into `BASH_REMATCH[1]` and onward.

Comment: Thanks so much Man! this really helped!